# workflow assign task to multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow

I have MOSS.
I want to make a page where a user, say administrator, could send some instructions to a server, for example using standard library and make task for a group of users forcing them to read files. After the reading users would press "already read it" and administrator would know who did it/who did not.

I created simple workflow in office designer and choose assigne task to Group1, which is in the sharepoint server.
After WF run everyone who is in Group1 get message about a task, that's great. However this task is general for group and if we go to the site section "current tasks", we can see it, while I want this task for every person in Group1.

Futher question, is it possible to create form where administrator will choose users for this task, 'cause now I munualy set group in WF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you developing a custom workflow within the SharePoint designer or Visual studio?

I don't know about SharePoint designer, but in Visual Studio it is as simple as using Replicator activity (kind of for-each loop). Also you can set Replicator Activity to run in paralell which i think is what you need for this situation.

Few notes:

1. Step would be in Replicator's Initialized event set CurrentChildData to users from your desired group. To expand groups in MOSS, you can use [Contact.ExpandGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558875.aspx).
2. Running Replicator Activity you must know how to reference data afterwards. You can use [this solution](http://trentacular.com/2008/12/sharepoint-workflow-getting-replicator-childdata-within-a-createtask-activity/).
3. When using CreateTask activity in replicator, use Parent sequence activity as parent for task token or [let me quote](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/11/23/developing-workflows-in-vs-part-3-five-steps-for-developing-your-workflow.aspx):

   > Note: if you have a task in a sequence
   >   inside the replicator activity,
   >   changing the “Owner Activity Name” to
   >   the sequence will automatically create
   >   a new token for every instance of the
   >   sequence.

The [ECM starter kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=38ca6b32-44be-4489-8526-f09c57cd13a5&displaylang=en) contains example of working workflow if you want to take example on how to get it working.